# What does this string mean?

Tags: php, smarty

Here is the code:

```
{assign var='xx' value=$pathToIncTemplate|cat:'body.tpl'}{include file=$xx}
```

We are concateting xx to the body template?
Thanks

Comment: This is not some PHP...

Comment: What actually it is? Any input field?

Comment: This question is quiet unclear. Please be me more detailed next time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are concatenating whatever is in `$pathToIncTemplate` and `'body.tpl'` and putting it into variable `$xx` and then between the curly braces, you're making sure that `'<$pathToIncTemplate>body.tpl'` it is being included.

So this code is used to add a template path to the template name of a template to be included in the current template being processed.

;-)